# Spring OAUTH2 server gives a error back saying "Full authentication is required to access this resourc" with 401

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

My curl command is working fine but only problem with post man 'POST METHOD' request

```
curl: curl act_client@localhost:8089/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d  username=jack -d password=act123

postman: http://localhost:8089/oauth/token?client_id=act_client&grant_type=password&username=jack&password=act123
```